# Spring-MVC Что происходит с ссылками при редактировании записи?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc

Взял готовый пример Spring3Demo.

Когда кликаю по ссылке *Edit* для редактирования записи, при этом из контроллера возвращаю эту же вью (`return "/users"`), URL всех ссылок меняется например с

`http://localhost:8080/spring3demo/user/8/edit` на `http://localhost:8080/spring3demo/user/8/user/8/edit`

Если снова нажать по любой из ссылок *Edit* и не обработать в контроллере запрос с этим "длинным" URL, получим ошибку `HTTP Status 404`.

И у меня теперь пара вопросов:

1. почему URL ссылок меняется?
2. как правильно производить
       редактирование (UPDATE) записи, если позволить пользователю нажимать ссылки *Edit* ?

Скрин-шот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вьюха: users.jsp

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="u">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${u.name}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${u.email}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${u.birth}"/></td>
        <td><a href='<c:url value="user/${u.id}/edit"/>'>Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>

<form:form modelAttribute="user">
        <form:hidden path="id"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Birth</td>
            <td><form:input path="birth"/></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Контроллер:

```
    @Controller
    public class UserController {
    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}/{action}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String action, Model model) {
        System.out.println("edit");
        User user = userService.getById(Long.parseLong(id));

        if (action.equals("edit")) {
            System.out.println("edit edit");
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            model.addAttribute("users", userService.getAll());
        }
        return "/users";
    }

    /* метод для обработки "длинного" урла */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{_id}/user/{id}/{action}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testEdit(@PathVariable String id
        , @PathVariable String _id, @PathVariable String action, Model model) {
       /* что-то делаем */

        return "redirect:/user";
    }
    }
```

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для несамодостаточных кусков кода следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

Comment: похоже я криво вопрос сформулировал - ни одной попытки дать ответ не было :(

Comment: такое случается. попробуйте переформулировать вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

- GET — получение ресурса (менять состояние системы через гет-запрос не кашерно)
- POST — создание ресурса
- PUT — обновление ресурса
- DELETE — удаление ресурса

Comment: Прочитал и не понимаю, а как это поможет автору вопроса?